# Silverlight ListBox not updating when not in XAML tree

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, listbox, observablecollection

Simplified version of the problem. So concentrate on the technical issue not user friendliness. ;)

I have a listbox filled with items from an ObservableCollection.
It is showed in my first view.

By selecting an item in the list the user goes to a another view.
I swap this view in, so the first one is not in the xaml tree.

In the second view they can perform actions.
One of the actions makes the item go away from the top list (like passing the item on to another user).

The first view listens for that event and can remove the item from the list.
Items.Remove(item)
Problem is that the item doesn't always disappear from the ListBox (but it does from the underlying list, I've checked with debug). I think it might have something to do with the view not being displayed at the moment the collection is updated. I've tested with setting SelectedItem to null, thinking that selection might keep it there after removal, but it made no difference.

Is this a known limitation, having to be visible for the listbox update to take effect?

Can I trigger something to make the observablecollection re-fire the notification?

Comment: Adding swapping views code snippet might help.

Comment: please share your code it might help us. Maybe you could pass the observable between the views. or reassign it to the listbox datasource

Comment: Hi, I prepared a sample that would simulate the more complex program. But I'm not seeing the problem there, it actually works. I'll continue to investigate and see what needs to be added to make the sample show the same problem.